# Creating Custom frameworks in OSX

Tags: ios, macos, frameworks, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have with me an AWS sdk for IOS version and I need one for a OSX version too. But I was not able to find one in Amazon site. So I was planning to port IOS version of AWS Sdk to OSX version. For that I made a few modifications in the source code and recompiled the framework. But unfortunately when I tried to run the recomipled OSX sdk, my app crashed withan error message **dyld: Library not loaded:** and **Reason: image not found**

Can any one please suggest me a good tutorial to create custom frameworks using XCode 4.2?

Answer (score 0):

I have a version that works for me on github. I don't build a dylib, I just add all the .m files to the project. IOS cannot use dylibs in any case. Its likely possible to build them though, just have not done it.

There are not many changes to be made...

https://github.com/tomandersen/aws-sdk-for-ios/

--Tom